# How to communicate with (bundled) dbus application in android?

Tags: android

I would like bundle one or more dbus applications with my android app. Is it possible to do that? If so, how would I approach this problem?

To be more specific, I would like to use [Telepathy](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/) and write a GUI for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

Not really.

You are welcome to make your own firmware that bundles in such binaries and ties them into the standard Linux boot process. Or, you are welcome to rewrite the native code to be a library and try to add it to your application via the NDK.

Android is not designed around apps deploying binary daemons, which (near as I can tell) is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Even if that binary daemon is only used by my app?